# Объединение ячеек с одинаковым значением

Tags: google-apps-script

Имею таблицу вида

| Дата | Действие |
| --- | --- |
| 31.05.22 | вверх |
| 31.05.22 | низ |
| 31.05.22 | низ |
| 01.06.22 | низ |
| 01.06.22 | вверх |
| 01.06.22 | низ |

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как сделать что бы ячейки с одинаковой датой объединялись в одну ячейку, а данные из второго столбца были не изменны

Comment: Как вариант - написать скрипт на Google apps script и пользоваться им

Comment: Это я понимаю. Только в скриптах я не силен. Был бы благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать в первом приближении что-то такое:

```js
function run() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = book.getSheetByName('Решение');
  sheet.getRange('A:A').breakApart();
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let buffer = { start: 0, value: String(values[0][0]) };
  values.forEach((row, i, arr) => {
    const cell = row[0] === '' ? buffer.value : String(row[0]);
    if ((buffer.value !== cell || i == arr.length - 1) && buffer.start !== i) {
      let lrx = 0;
      if (i == arr.length - 1) lrx = 1;
      if (i == arr.length - 1 && buffer.value !== cell) lrx = 0;
      sheet.getRange(buffer.start + 1, 1, i - buffer.start + lrx).merge();
      buffer.start = i;
      buffer.value = cell;
    }
  });
}
```

К сожалению, с пустыми ячейками в обхединении такое работать не будет, т.е. нужно либо предзаполнять данные, либо обрабатывать `breakApart` через внешнее хранение.

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SPtNpvRKbGNnHzkOEN_APXrErTNJsCQLsLNTrCfveUI/edit?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ваш труд. Скрипт объединяет ячейки всего один раз, новые записи он уже не объединяет.
Я поставил этот скрипт на триггер тип события "при редактировании"
https://i.imgur.com/SLNmJOA.jpg

Comment: Может сделать что бы скрипт сначала разъединял все ячейки в первом столбце, а потом снова объединял все ячейки с одинаковым значением? И можно ли сделать что бы скрипт объединял ячейки начиная с определённой строки, а не с первой?

Comment: Может, в задаче этого не было =) Вообще, лучше, конечно, чтобы он объединял, а потом еще раз разбивал, т.к. могут быть изменения.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, что не полностью описал задачу. Извиняюсь.
Данные в столбце дата изменяться не будут.

Comment: @Дмитрий, самое правильное теперь - это отметь ответ решением.

Comment: Большое спасибо за вашу работу. Отметил решение.